# How can i make my browse dialog go to a specific folder in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in VBA and when I click the browse button to get the folder location it always preloads the my documents folder. How can I automatically preload to the folder where the excel file is stored so that all the user has to do it click ok?

For example:

> The user wants to load a folder. He clicks the browse button. The
>   dialogue to select folder pops up. And it's already at the folder
>   where the excel file is stored. The user then clicks ok to load the
>   folder.

I have this code that loads the folder with the dialogue box:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
       .Title = "Select A Folder Containing Your EM Traces"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
       sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `I have a macro in VBA` then please remove the VB.NET tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `InitialFileName` property of the `FileDialog` object. For example with your code:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
       .Title = "Select A Folder Containing Your EM Traces"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .InitialFileName = "C:\Some Folder" 'Set the directory here
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
       sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use wildcards to preselect a folder with limited data you could do it this way:

```
Sub dialog_pre_open_folder_from_wildcard_info()
    inputPath = GetFolder()
End Sub
    
    
Function GetFolder() As String

Dim File_Dialog_Box As Office.FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

Set File_Dialog_Box = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
inputPath = "W:\Job Folders\" & Sheets("Summary").Range("E1").Value & "*"

If Sheets("Summary").Range("E1").Value = "" Then 'if this isnt here it will create it in all the job folders.
    MsgBox ("enter Job number to continue")
    Exit Function
End If

'get fixed path
fixedPath = Left$(inputPath, InStrRev(inputPath, "\"))
'wildcard part
wildPath = Mid$(inputPath, InStrRev(inputPath, "\") + 1)
'//loop fixed path looking for a wildcard match on subdirs
aDir = Dir$(fixedPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)
Do While Len(aDir)
    If aDir <> "." And aDir <> ".." And GetAttr(fixedPath & aDir) And vbDirectory Then
        If aDir Like wildPath Then
            'MsgBox "found: " & fixedPath & aDir 'for testing
            'the shell command will open the folder
            'Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & fixedPath & aDir & "", vbNormalFocus
            newinputPath = fixedPath & aDir & "\"
        End If
    End If

    aDir = Dir$()
Loop

With File_Dialog_Box
    .Title = "Select a Job Folder Location to Save your CTL Project"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    If newinputPath = "" Then
    .InitialFileName = "W:\Job Folders\"
    Else
    .InitialFileName = newinputPath
    End If
    
    If .Show = -1 Then
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        sItem = ""
    End If
    

End With

GetFolder = sItem

Set File_Dialog_Box = Nothing

End Function
```